# Microsoft Office 2003 applications crash on 'Save As' to a network mapped drive

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, sp3, microsoft-office-2003

Hey guys, so I'm not sure if it belongs on ServerFault forums so figured I'd ask here first because its a workstation/client side issue.

I have a client where we have windows server 2003 setup, with windows xp professional setup on all the workstations. We've setup a 'domain' and all workstations logon to the domain (authenticated by the Windows Domain Controller), and in the logon script we map drives on to each workstation.

Everything is working peachy except for one workstation, where when I open a file in excel from a mapped drive, it opens fine, but when I go to hit Save As, the Save As dialog pops and hangs up. I cannot perform any other action in excel. When I try cancel the Save As dialog, excel crashes.

The mapped drive opens up fine in Windows Explorer.

To further investigate this issue, I created a new blank text document on the network drive in Windows Explorer. I then opened it. Then hit save as, and the Save As dialog opened up fine and it would let me save the document.

I repeated the above steps for a word document. However this time the Save As dialog hung/froze again. So I'd imagine its a Microsoft Office Issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that Office apps are being run as a different user that doesn't have permissions to that share?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had an answer for you but I do have some concurrence and additional context to add. I am having the same problem. Mine is even simpler in setup:

I have a drive letter mapped to a localhost UNC (to make it easier to save to a particular folder). Recently I started having the same problem you describe. Here's what I've noticed:

All "save as" dialogs are slow but in Office 2003 it hangs seemingly forever. In textpad when I try to save a file, it hangs for 2-3 seconds and then saves. Whereas in Excel it will hang forever.

What's especially weird is that if I copy/rename the file in explorer, that works ok and once the new file exists, I can open it with Excel, make changes click "Save" and the save is fast!

So this is baffling to me - save dialogs are quick, but save as hangs. If I do copy/rename operations from a CMD prompt everything is snappy on the drive.

So I'm totally flummoxed. It doesn't appear to be a drive permissions thing (the current user has full control/read/write). It's not a network thing because the UNC is in format: \localhost\drive_letter\folder\folder

It's not a universal problem b/c DOS works fine. Textpad is slightly slow and Office apps hang forever.

The only other drive letters I have are mapped to a USB drive that seems to work fine. To make sure it's not something funny on the USB side, I removed that device. Same probs.

I'd love any diagnostic suggestions anyone might have.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Midgley

What I ended up doing was to recreate the windows profile. So I went to C:\Documents and Settings, and renamed the (username) folder to (username).bak. Then relogged in as the user and moved over his files, and outlook pst files, to the new profile, and it slow save as dialog problem disappeared.

As far as diagnosing, I believe it could be 2 problems. I didn't have the time to diagnosing the problem, so I just reset the profile as I've described above. But if I had to guess I'd imagine the problem may lie in

1. Either its a file sharing protocol error. Only way to diagnose that I'd imagine is Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor.
2. Or its a workstation setting which got changed and needs to be reset. No way to know how to find that out. You could probably try doing a diff of registry backups (they should be saved as text files, the registry backups should).

thinking back, I could've tried a system restore to 1 previous day and see if it fixed the problem. Then I'd imagine its option #2 problem

Answer (score 0):

Check any other drives you might have mapped in Windows.  They might be mapped with expired credentials or the connection might not be working.  If there are other mapped drives, try disconnecting them, if possible, to see if it comes up any faster.

I remember in XP having the "Retrieving list of folders..." message come up CONSTANTLY and it drove me nuts til I found out I had a drive mapped and hadn't remapped it since I changed a password.